# Python Split if there is only one element

Tags: python, split

I am trying to do a Python Split but there seems to be a problem with my logic.

I have some data, separated with a semicolon. Some example of my data would be like:

- 89;50;20
- 40

I only want to retrieve one value from each row. Like for example in row 1, i only want the last value which is 20, and i want 40 from the second row.

I tried using the following code:

```
fields = fields.split(";")[-1]
```

It works for the first row, i got 20. but i am unable to get the data from second row as it has only one element in the split.

Then I tried using an if-else condition like below but the code is unable to run.

```
if (len(fields.split(";")) > 0):

    fields = fields.split(";")[-1]
else:
    pass
```

Anybody knows how to deal with this problem ? What I am achieve is that if there is only 1 value in that row I will read it. If there is more than one value, I split it and take the last value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strip` to normalize input, the problem is there is an extra `;` for one number situation, so we should remove it first.

```
In [1]: def lnum(s):
   ...:     return s.strip(';').split(';')[-1]
   ...: 

In [2]: lnum('89;50;20')
Out[2]: '20'

In [3]: lnum('89;')
Out[3]: '89'

In [5]: lnum('10;')
Out[5]: '10'
```

Comment: better to use `rstrip`

Answer (score 0):

So, if you see when you split the string - `'40;'` using semicolon (`;`), you get a list of two strings - `['40', '']`. So, `fields.split(";")[-1]` returns an empty string for the input `'40;'`.

So, either you strip the last semicolon `;` before splitting as follows.

```
print('40;'.rstrip(';').split(';')[-1])
```

OR, you can do:

```
fields = '40;'.split(';')
if fields[-1]:
    print(fields[-1])
else:
    print(fields[-2])
```

I prefer the first approach than the `if/else` approach. Also, have a look at the [.strip(), .lstrip(), .rstrip()](http://ics.misterv.ca/6-0-python/python-notes/string-processing/-strip-lstrip-rstrip) functions.

Comment: Hi I am sorry, I removed the semicolon in my second row of data, just realized if there is only one element, there will be no semi colon at the end.

Comment: @decemberrobot then you shouldn't have got any error !!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use re module.

```
from re import findall

s1 = '80;778;20'
s2 = '40'

res1 = findall( '\d+', s1)
res2 = findall( '\d+', s2)

print res1[-1]
print res2[-1]
```